# Why am I getting 'Unexpected 1' in JSHint?

Tags: javascript, html, jshint

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //Create the context

//more code (width, height defined elsewhere)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0.35 * width, 0);
ctx.lineTo(0.35 * width, 0.65 * height);
ctx.lineTo(1 * width, 0.65 * height); //JSHint is complaining about the 1 here
ctx.stroke();
```

Why am I getting an error here?

Comment: Tried that, still got the same error

Comment: I tried on jshint.com and can't reproduce your problem. Please be more precise in your question regarding how you get this error.

Comment: Well `1 * width` might looks as an error to someone, because why do you want to multiply a value by one.

Comment: Good point, I guess I was just trying to be consistent with the calls to lineTo

Comment: There are cases where multiplying by 1 **is** useful, for example to ensure you get a number.

Comment: @dystroy yes there are cases where `1 *` is used to make sure that the result is a number, but there you should use `parseInt(number, 10)` or something like that to make clear that is is because of that. In the worst case e.g. a minifier will remove the `1 *`

Comment: @t.niese depends : doesn't work if width isn't a string but for example a boolean.

Comment: @dystroy That's a valid point for sure. [opinion based]I still would avoid to use a `1 * ` in favor of `parseInt` and a `NaN` check when I can't be sure that it is a number or at least wrap it in a custom `makeNumber()` function[/opinion based].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a meaningless operation, multiplying by 1 doesn't do anything. Just use width.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because multiplication by 1 is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use :

```
ctx.lineTo(width, 0.65 * height);
```

as far as i can tell 1 * anything will most likely give the same result

Comment: *" 1 * anything will give the same result"*. This is just false.

Comment: Can you explain @dystroy

Comment: @AllisonC Try `1*true`. See this real program example : https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/plugins/ludogene/client-scripts/Tribo.js#L122

Comment: @AllisonC 1*null=0 and 1*undefined=NaN

Comment: sorry people as I said, it was far as i knew.

Comment: @dystroy as long as you stay within the reasonable part of javascript, the statement is true. For numbers (as is the case in the question) it *is* always true.

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard Where did you see width defined ? It's frequent to get widths as strings in JS for example...

Comment: @dystroy That is a completely unrelated issue. I assume `width` is a number because he is generally using it as such in the question (and also because JSHint doesn't complain).